# SAS fails to fit a mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, sas

Here are some simulated data:

```
    library(mvtnorm)
    I <- 3 # positions (fixed factor)
    J <- 4 # tubes (random factor)
    K <- 4 # repeats 
    n <- I*J*K
    set.seed(123)
    tube <- rep(1:J, each=I)
    position <- rep(LETTERS[1:I], times=J)
    Mu_i <- 3*(1:I)
    Mu_ij <- c(t(rmvnorm(J, mean=Mu_i)) )  
    tube <- rep(tube, each=K)
    position <- rep(position, each=K)
    Mu_ij <- rep(Mu_ij, each=K)
    dat <- data.frame(tube, position, Mu_ij)
    sigmaw <- 2
    dat$y <- rnorm(n, dat$Mu_ij, sigmaw)
    dat$tube <- factor(dat$tube)

> str(dat)
'data.frame':   48 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ tube    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ position: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ Mu_ij   : num  2.44 2.44 2.44 2.44 6.13 ...
     $ y       : num  3.24 2.66 1.33 6.01 7.12 ...
> head(dat)
  tube position    Mu_ij        y
1    1        A 2.439524 3.241067
2    1        A 2.439524 2.660890
3    1        A 2.439524 1.327842
4    1        A 2.439524 6.013351
5    1        B 6.129288 7.124989
6    1        B 6.129288 2.196053
```

I fit a mixed model with R, it works well:

```
> library(lme4)
> lmer(y ~ position + (0+position|tube), data=dat)
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: y ~ position + (0 + position | tube) 
   Data: dat 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 212.6 231.3  -96.3    194.8   192.6
Random effects:
 Groups   Name      Variance Std.Dev. Corr          
 tube     positionA 0.30123  0.54885                
          positionB 0.68317  0.82654  -0.695        
          positionC 1.66666  1.29099  -0.408  0.940 
 Residual           3.14003  1.77201                
Number of obs: 48, groups: tube, 4

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   3.3533     0.5211   6.435
positionB     3.1098     0.8923   3.485
positionC     5.6138     1.0144   5.534

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
          (Intr) postnB
positionB -0.753       
positionC -0.651  0.744
```

But the same model does not work well with SAS:

```
PROC MIXED DATA=dat ;
CLASS POSITION TUBE ;
MODEL y = POSITION ;
RANDOM POSITION / subject=TUBE type=UN G GCORR ;
RUN; QUIT;
```

gives

```
 Estimated G matrix is not positive definite.
                         Estimated G Matrix

               Row    Effect      position    tube        Col1        Col2        Col3

                 1    position    A           1        0.08895     -0.5823     -0.1545
                 2    position    B           1        -0.5823      0.1455      1.2431
                 3    position    C           1        -0.1545      1.2431      1.4835
```

Is it possible to remedy this failure ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the SAS part, but I ran this model in `R` and got a warning message:

Comment: What does the warning say ?

Comment: Oops, my message got cut off. My warning message says:
`Warning message:
In mer_finalize(ans) : singular convergence (7)`
which usually happens when there are variance components estimated to be 0. I imagine that my `R` warning is related to the SAS warning. You might want to graph the data.

Comment: That's strange: I don't have this warning. If you type head(dat), you get the same as me ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Could it be the version of `lme4` and/or `R`? I'm using `R version 2.14.2` and `lme4_0.999375-42` on a Mac (OS X 10.6.8).

Comment: I use R-2.14.2 on Windows and the last update of lme4.

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread, but I just ran into something that may shed light on this. On my research team, some of us use R on a Mac and some on Windows, some of which are 32-bit and some 64. The 64-bit versions of R give the same warnings as the Macs, but the 32-bit versions don't. However, if I write `warnings(fm)`, `R` displays the same warnings as in the other versions. If you ask for the warnings for the model on your machine, do you recieve that `Warning message: In mer_finalize(ans) : singular convergence (7)` message?

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as off topic.  This is more about statistics than anything else.  There was also a met thread  a while back about questions such as this, comparing methods from two stat packages, where the consensus was to leave such questions here.

Answer (score 7):

The SAS model you have fitted is not the same as the one you fitted with `lme4::lmer`. You have specified an unstructured variance-covariance matrix for the residual error within subjects in SAS, whereas `lme4::lmer` does not support this structure.